# Meaning of "up to 2 hours before <event>"?

Tags: time

While traveling in Europe I came across sentence that read opposite to what I believe was intended.

To be more specific, how should one interpret:

> Customers must check in online up to 2 hours before the scheduled flight departure.

The reason I find it confusing is that if I replace "up to" with antonym "at least" then I get

> Customers must check in online at least 2 hours before the scheduled flight departure.

In this case it is super clear to me that customers must check in 2, 3, 4 or more hours before flight departure as airline intended, but not 1 hour before departure. So if I replace "up to" with antonym "at least", then the meaning should have become the opposite, no?

Comment: Since airlines want confirmations in time to do something, they don't want them at the last minute. So, up to a certain time makes sense.

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes, this is a clear cut case what airline's intent was. However, what if there was a similar situation where intent was not so clear?

Comment: ... If _intent is not so clear_, surely you have answered your own question, 389. 'Flying planes can be dangerous' is notoriously non-disambiguable without context (which can include asking the author). Such vexing cases occur.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do see the OP's point though. If a restaurant said that "The complementary apertifs will be available in the cocktail lounge to all customers up to half an hour before the time of their booking" that would obviously be the opposite of the quoted airline statement.

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous.

Comment: It's simply poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ambiguous as written.

"up to" could refer to the number 2, in which case it means "at most 2 hours before". This parse is:

> Customers must check in online (up to 2) hours before the scheduled flight departure.

But it can also refer to the metaphorical movement of time. In that case, it means the time period that begins when check-in opens (1 day before) until 2 hours before the departure time.

This parse is:

> Customers must check in online up to (2 hours before the scheduled flight departure).

The latter is the intended meaning.

Comment: The 2 hours is the important part, the rest can be inferred. There are ways of making it unambiguous, eg at the earliest, before/after.

Comment: @Barmar your suggestion to parse sentence in two different ways with parenthesis was helpful. However, how to know which of the two parses to pick in other situations where inferred intent would be not so clear? In other words, did you pick latter based on inferred intent alone or on something else too?

Comment: There's no way to know from the grammar, you have to use the context and common sense. That's what "ambiguous" means.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the *real* meaning is along the lines of:  "Customers may only use the online check-in if the scheduled flight departure is more than two hours out.  If it is within 2 hours of scheduled departure time, an in-person check-in is required.

Thus, *If customers are going to check-in online, it *must* be more than two hours before the scheduled departure.*

I think the interpretation:

> Customers must check in online up to (2 hours before the scheduled flight departure).

is incorrect because this implies that an online check-in is mandatory.